# Remove user from database

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new to PHP and I've come across the following problem. User is added to database when he/she logs in (page2.php) but what I'm having trouble with is removing the user from the database when he/she goes to page3.php. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Page2.php

```
        <?php 
          echo "<p> Hello World!</p>";

        // php 5.3 and up can throw an error if this is not set  
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");


        // much of the example code on the web forgets to include these HttpClients, for some reason
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );

        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

        // This one is also often left out
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');

        // store your $HOSTNAME, $APPID and $SECRET in this file:
        require_once( '../docs/my_app_credentials.php' );

        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
        use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
        use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
        use Facebook\GraphObject;

        session_start();

        // init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($APPID,$SECRET);

        // login helper with uri
        $PAGENAME="page2.php";
        $REDIRECT_URL="http://".$HOSTNAME.'/'.$PAGENAME;

        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $REDIRECT_URL );
        try {
            echo "<p> about to try to get session: the helper variable: </p>";
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        //  echo "<p> the session variable:</p>";
        //  var_dump($session);
            } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
          // When Facebook returns an error
          echo "<p> There was a facebook request exception</p>";
        } catch( \Exception $ex ) {
          echo "<p> There was a validation failure</p>";
          var_dump($ex);

          // When validation fails or other local issues
        }
          echo "<p> 'get session' block now completed...</p>";

        // see if we have a session
        if ( isset( $session ) ) {
          echo "<p> Now try to get a graph node</p>";

          // graph api request for user data
          $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
          $response = $request->execute();
          // get response
          $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

          // print data
          echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );


          $FBID=$graphObject->getProperty('id');
          $FIRSTNAME=$graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
          $SECONDNAME=$graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
          $TOKEN=$_GET['code'];

          //write code to check if current user is in database
          //if not add them to database
          //finally, give link to page3.php which removes them (user) from database.
          $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
          $query = "SELECT FBID FROM USERS WHERE FBID='$FBID'";

          $result = $con->query($query);

          if ($result) {
          echo "Username already exists!";
        }
          else
          {

           $con->query("INSERT INTO USERS (FBID,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,TOKEN) VALUES ('$FBID','$FIRSTNAME','$SECONDNAME','$TOKEN')");
            echo"user inserted";

          }


        } else {
          // show login url
          echo 'No session was set. Try logging in again by clicking here: <a href="' . "page1.php". '">Login</a>';
        }


        ?>
```

Page3.php

```
    <?php  

       $con->query("DROP FROM USERS (FBID,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,TOKEN) VALUES ('$FBID','$FIRSTNAME','$SECONDNAME','$TOKEN')");

    ?>
```

Comment: Where are the values of those variables in Page3.php supposed to come from? If that is all your code inside that page, then _of course_ it does not work. Your first step should be to configure PHP’s error_reporting properly, so that it tells you about stuff like this. And then your second step is to learn some PHP basics, because if you seriously think this should work as it is, then you clearly lack some very basic knowledge.

Comment: ...also, some mysql basics might be useful. with a very simple google search you should find out that "DROP" is not for deleting a row in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong.

You want `DELETE` not `DROP`. Example:

```
DELETE FROM USERS WHERE FBID='$FBID';
```

Deleting where something is in one field will delete the whole row, not just the one field (so the user will be deleted).

Make sure that in `page3.php` you are calling `$FBID` either through the facebook API or using `$_POST`.

To send data through `POST` in php, you can do something like this:

```
<form action='page3.php' method='post' name='page3form'>
  <?php
    echo "<input type='text' name='FBID' value='$FBID' /> 
  ?>
</form>

<script>
  document.page3form.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Could you please shine a bit more light on how to call the $FBID using $_POST ? @BeatAlex

Comment: Thanks for your response, How would I put a href link to page3.php on page2.php without killing the session

Comment: You could use `session_start();` @Redlight